# How to make your more experienced and authoritative teammates not to create 'fast temporary solutions'?

Tags: coding-style

I'm currently working on a small short-lived project. But despite the size it's complicated enough with very unclear logic. That's why it was started by more experienced developers. They work on it from time to time because it's not their main project.

They made some code drafts with numerous places which 'would be rewritten in the nearest future'. After that they added several another 'temporary pieces'. And then again..

So, now the project is a mess of 'half-working' pieces of code with some hardcoded values, like file names or some constants which 'will be replaced latter with working parts'. The API is awful (nobody thinks about it actually).

And it's really, really hard to do development now (for me it's the main and only project). I caught myself thinking that I spent about an hour every day just to understand again all that tricky 'temporary' things and API weaknesses. And after that hour my brain melts.

I can't just say "guys, your code smells like a trash dump". What's the correct way?

Comment: If it's truly a "short-lived" project, then soon the code quality will be irrelevant. What do you mean by "short-lived", anyway? Typically 'having an API' and 'being short-lived' don't really go together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the ultimate problem is they are writing code and not taking responsibility for its quality.

If this goes against the culture of the organization, it's a matter of making the situation known others. If the developers don't know, and have a modicum of empathy, I would take the "I don't quite understand this. Could you spend a few minutes walking me through it?" with them. They should soon realize what they are doing to you, and good programmers will adjust their practices. This may also have to be done via the management hierarchy-- "In order to progress on project X, I need Y hours of the programmers' time to work with their code effectively." It should either happen or bring up a "Why" conversation that should lead to changes.

If this is the culture of the organization, that's unfortunate. It may mean that the programmers producing the code don't care, and nor do any of the management. This is a bit of a political question-- who is most capable and/or interested in seeing this change? Find allies and proceed best you can. A candid conversation with the developers may be the best choice, as they are the people capable of change and no one else is going to induce them to-- so just ask outright.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Push for implementation of a formal code review process. Then they won't dare write code like that in the first place. I recommend using a collaborative tool like SmartBear's Code Collaborator or the free ReviewBoard.
Just like people drive slower when they know the cops are watching, they write better code if they know someone is going to be looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Are these 'other developers' no longer working on the project? And if so, are you the main person working on it? If the answer to both of these is "yes" the the project is yours. Start to make incremental improvements to make it more readable.

You might also like to show the code to a more experienced developer who didn't work on the project. See if they agree that the code is hard to maintain. Suggest to your boss that you set some time aside to 'finish off' the temporary work and bring it to a point where it is maintainable.

Implementing a formal code review process is also a good idea if you want to prevent this happening again.

And remember it may not have been the other developers fault. Sometimes people are told to spend the minimum amount of time, or are told that the code will be thrown away.